# Are there any attempts at creating ASIC for bitcoin mining?

Tags: asic, mining-hardware

I take reference to the [Question here which compares ASIC with FPGA](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/103/whats-the-difference-between-an-asic-and-an-fpga-which-is-better-for-mining). In this question someone quotes a company called [Largecoin](http://largecoin.com/) that is said to be at the development of such an ASIC. However their web page does not really look promising. It rather looks like some investment seeking attempt. (Quote from the only content on the web page: "For more information about LargeCoin, visit largecoin.com")

I would like to know if there are *any other* attempts at building ASIC for bitcoin mining?

Comment: LargeCoin actually seem to be very close to releasing their first ASIC: http://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/qj9ov/somebody_please_perform_an_roi_on_the_30k/

Comment: Well, yeah, I know, so I didn't post it as an answer but rather a comment.

Answer (score 4):

The closest thing to ASIC seems to be the BitForce series which has just been released and customers it seems are just begining to receive their first orders.

From the website:

> Is your system based on FPGA or ASIC technology?
>
> The BitForce processor card is a proprietary implementation of both
>   FPGA and ASIC technology.

As far as I'm aware, the actual chip design won't be released, but it seems legit now that people have begun testing the potential.

http://www.butterflylabs.com/

Comment: BFL's first-gen products were FPGA based, the ASIC mention was either marketing speak, or a reference to the future product Bitforce SC which is indeed ASIC-based.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ASIC devices reportedly under development:

1. [OpenBitASIC](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=76351.0).
2. Butterfly Labs [BitForce SC](http://www.butterflylabs.com/bitforce-sc-release-notes/).
3. [LargeCoin](http://largecoin.com/) which you mentioned.
4. [Vladimir's company](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=75298.0).

Comment: thanks for your answer. 1) I could claim to have triggered this development (1 month after my question)
2) This company seems to be serious. At the time when I asked the question their only product was FPGA - not ASIC. Lets wait until October.
3) No update since. Very scam-like.
4) Please *read* the thread. This really looks like another scam.
Although people seem to be very exited about ASIC, I hardly see that term ever used beyond marketing speech.

Comment: 3) LargeCoin didn't take anyone's money. Usually when someone is doing a scam they take money. 4) I read some of it. Vladimir is a well-known member of the Bitcoin community. I don't know exactly what his plans are but I doubt they could be called a scam.

Comment: That's why I only said "scam-like". Besides: Do you *really* know that they didn't take anyones money? Maybe they still wait before they run... Maybe... who knows? Their website is the same static page since months.
And: Iv'e read Valdimirs posts too. Do you have another "proof" that he's the owner of LargeCoin besides these posts? It's not my intension to offend anyone, I'm just applying the necessary prudence in this this higly anonymized business.

Comment: @user1127914: Yes, I preordered from LargeCoin and they didn't take my money, other people reported that they preordered and they didn't take their money, and nobody reported that they took his money. This is the first time I've heard the theory that Vladimir and Largecoin are related, do you have any evidence? And, what anonymized business? The identities of both Ken Simpson from Largecoin and Vladimir Marchenko are known.